# Shortest distance and calculus of variation.

Tags: calculus, geometry, calculus-of-variations

Every answer to the question "show that the shortest path between two points on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the line segment joining them", seems to rely on some version of calculus of variation.

My problem with that approach is that most of them make the assumption that the path is the graph of a smooth function, rather than a generic curve. Okay, we may exclude the possibility of self-intersection, but how can we eliminate the possiblity that the curve may not be the graph of a function or not (piecewise) smooth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not true. See: [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#General_approach): we normally define the length of a curve as a (potentially infinite) supremum of all the lengths (in the "standard" sense) of *polygonal lines* joining the beginning and the end of the curve and "inscribed" in the curve. We say that the curve is "rectifiable" if this supremum is finite.

With that definition, the fact that the straight line is the shortest follows pretty much immediately from the definition. Pretty much, the only slightly nontrivial bit is to prove that the length of the straight line (in this new sense) is the same as the length of the straight line (in the standard sense). This is true because, for every polygonal line "inscribed" in a straight line, the (standard) length of it is exactly the same as the (standard) length of the original straight line.

---

This consideration works in any $\mathbb R^n$. However, it does not scale well to other manifolds, because those may be locally *homeomorphic* with $\mathbb R^n$ but not locally *isometric* with $\mathbb R^n$. The common way of adding metric to manifolds (which is: adding a *metric tensor*) requires differentiability of the maps between charts in the atlas (i.e. the manifold must be differentiable), in order for the metric tensor to allow for a change in co-ordinates when switching from one chart to another. *That* approach scales a lot better, but requires differentiability, and in *that* approach, the length of the shortest path is calculated using calculus of variations. This is probably what you had in mind in your question.

Comment: "With that definition, the fact that the straight line is the shortest follows pretty much immediately from the definition." This bit I am not sure. How does it follow immediately that of all curves, the strainght line is the shortest length curve?

Comment: The straight line is a polygonal line already. Thus, *it is one of those polygonal lines* that you can inscribe in a curve joining two points. Thus, the length of the curve (the supremum of the lengths of the polygonal lines) is greater than or equal to the length of any of those polygonal lines - including the straight line!

Comment: @jsdifjew (Cont'd): Recall what the supremum is: the *least upper bound* - i.e. it is still *an upper bound*. It is greater (or equal) than any values in the set for which it is a supremum.